# Unable to solve this error : Unclosed String

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unable to solve a syntax error. Unclosed string is the error when i am trying to validate it.

```
function addNewCultureRow($row, $case, $specimen) {
    var $uniqueID = "." + $row + $case + "." + $specimen;
    var $tableRows = "<tr><td>" + $row + "<td><input id='localLevel" + $uniqueID + '" type="edit">' +
                        "<td><input id='colony" + $uniqueID + '" type="edit">' +
                        "<td><input id='description" + $uniqueID + '" type="edit">' +
                        "<td><input id='oxidase" + $uniqueID + '" type="edit">' +
                        "<td><input id='isolation1" + $uniqueID + '" type="edit">' +
                        "<td><input id='isolation2" + $uniqueID + '" type="edit">' +
                        "<td><input id='bioChemComments" + $uniqueID + '" type="edit">' +
                        "<td><input id='IDMALDI" + $uniqueID + '" type="edit">' +
                        "<td><input id='sensiID" + $uniqueID + '" type="edit">' +
                        "<td><input id='organism-" + $case + "-" + $specimen + "544' type='select'>" +
                        "<td><input id='localComments" + $uniqueID + '" type="edit">' +
                        "<td><input id='comments-" + $case + "-" + $specimen + "-544-new' type='edit'>" +
                        "<td><input id='result-" + $case + "-" + $specimen + "544-new' type='select'>";
    return ($tableRows);
}
```

Comment: You are using quotes and double quotes without a rigid pattern. You start a string with double quotes and the switch to single quotes

Answer (score 3):

I think this is coming from this lines

```
"<td><input id='colony"
```

You need to close the inner quote.

Comment: Not only that, but every line has the same problem

Comment: Yes.I wanted to mention this type in every line.

Comment: Can someone give me an example..? the error mostly starts from line 3

Comment: "<td><input id='localLevel" change this to "<td><input id='localLevel' "

Comment: You are opening id quotes with single quotes and closing with double. That's the problem

Answer (score 1):

Thakur was correct in his response, that you have ' and " mixed up a few times. If you want to avoid this sort of issue in the future, you might want to consider using template strings, for example:

```
var $tableRows = `<tr><td>${$row}<td><input id='localLevel ${$uniqueID}' type="edit">
                <td><input id='colony ${$uniqueID}' type="edit">
                <td><input id='description ${$uniqueID}' type="edit">
                <td><input id='oxidase ${$uniqueID}' type="edit">
                <td><input id='isolation1 ${$uniqueID}' type="edit">
                <td><input id='isolation2 ${$uniqueID}' type="edit">
                <td><input id='bioChemComments ${$uniqueID}' type="edit">
                <td><input id='IDMALDI ${$uniqueID}' type="edit">
                <td><input id='sensiID ${$uniqueID}' type="edit">
                <td><input id='organism-${$case}-${$specimen}-544' type='select'>
                <td><input id='localComments ${$uniqueID}' type="edit">
                <td><input id='comments-${$case}-${$specimen}-544-new' type='edit'>
                <td><input id='result-${$case}-${$specimen}-544-n' type='edit'>
                `;
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse all '" to "' and type="edit" should be type='edit' like this:

```
function addNewCultureRow($row, $case, $specimen) {
    var $uniqueID = "." + $row + $case + "." + $specimen;
    var $tableRows = "<tr><td>" + $row + "<td><input id='localLevel" + $uniqueID + "' type='edit'>" +
                        "<td><input id='colony" + $uniqueID + "' type='edit'>" +
                        "<td><input id='description" + $uniqueID + "' type='edit'>" +
                        "<td><input id='oxidase" + $uniqueID + "' type='edit'>" +
                        "<td><input id='isolation1" + $uniqueID + "' type='edit'>" +
                        "<td><input id='isolation2" + $uniqueID + "' type='edit'>" +
                        "<td><input id='bioChemComments" + $uniqueID + "' type='edit'>" +
                        "<td><input id='IDMALDI" + $uniqueID + "' type='edit'>" +
                        "<td><input id='sensiID" + $uniqueID + "' type='edit'>" +
                        "<td><input id='organism-" + $case + "-" + $specimen + "544' type='select'>" +
                        "<td><input id='localComments" + $uniqueID + "' type='edit'>" +
                        "<td><input id='comments-" + $case + "-" + $specimen + "-544-new' type='edit'>" +
                        "<td><input id='result-" + $case + "-" + $specimen + "544-new' type='select'>";
    return ($tableRows);
}
```